# Require two fingers to initiate drag-drop event

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm trying to create a MS Surface 2.0 application that involves multiple SurfaceListBox elements and children dataitems. The key interaction here is dragging the dataitems along the list boxes in a drag-drop fashion (which I know has been heavily documented, I've been doing my reading).

I've been using the MSDN article [provided here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727837.aspx) to answer a few of my questions about how the whole drag-drop event occurs in Surface, but I'm definitely still learning. One thing they mention is that it's possible to require two touches to initiate the drag-drop event so that one finger can still be used to scroll the listboxes. However, I can't seem to get that code to work.

```
        //The following 15 lines are provided for background.
        FrameworkElement findSource = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        SurfaceListBoxItem draggedElement = null;

        // Find the touched SurfaceListBoxItem object.
        while (draggedElement == null && findSource != null)
        {
            if ((draggedElement = findSource as SurfaceListBoxItem) == null)
            {
                findSource = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(findSource) as FrameworkElement;

                btnEditProj.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                btnDeleteProj.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }

        }

        //THIS IS THE PART IN QUESTION.
        if (draggedElement == null || draggedElement.TouchesCapturedWithin.Count == 0)
        {
        return;
        }
```

I can see that the first part checks to see if the element is still not identified as a SurfaceListBoxItem, and the second part checks to see if it has been touched before in the same initiation (which would require two fingers, then), but it throws an error, stating that it can't have, first, that kind of operator with a method group and an integer and, after changing it to a single equals sign (=), tells me that I can't use || between a bool and a method group.

I'm still quite the novice when it comes to C# in general, so I assume I'm missing some sort of simple syntax or logic element here, or if how MS implemented TouchesCapturedWithin changed from SDK 1.0 to 2.0 (or maybe I just can't transpose code to the right section), but if anyone can throw me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I've solved my problem.

Like I said, I'm still learning, so I was hesitant to question my own doubts about what was written. However, the "Count" being used in this example is a method (which threw me off in the code, as the intellisense told me to use less than and greater than (<>) signs, so I thought it wasn't a method.) However, upon trying that line with parentheses after it:

```
    if (draggedElement == null || draggedElement.TouchesCapturedWithin.Count() == 0) 
        { 
        return; 
        }
```

I found that it actually tracked one and two fingers correctly.

I guess MSDN changed the way the TouchesCapturedWithin.Count() method was implemented between Surface 1.0 and 2.0? Or someone there just didn't test that portion of code...